# TextField resignFirstResponder not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have created 5 textFields.

And, create tap in tableView to hide keyboard of textfield

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTableView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTable)];
    [_tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapTableView];

-(void)tapTable{
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt3 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt4 resignFirstResponder];
    [txt5 resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But, it's not hide keyboard, it's called tapTable but not hide keyboard.

How can I resolved this problem!

Comment: Have you checked IBOutlet is given properly or not?

Comment: TableView have IBOutlet
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening due to you didn't set your IBOutlet and write more preety code as given below. Don't need to resign each and every text field.

```
-(void)tapTable{
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.
Just use

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```